# Tailwind CSS show text under image

Tags: css, tailwind-css

i am trying to show text under image for responsive design.
right now it is showing behind icon. how i can show text below icon.

[CODE](https://play.tailwindcss.com/I9TegIY1Cs)

[image]

```
  <link
  rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
/>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap mt-4 border-2 border-gray-500 p-8 m-auto w-1/4  items-center justify-center">
  <div class=" absolute  fas fa-book-reader text-6xl text-gray-600"></div>
  <div class=" text-base"> Caring Enviroment</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: put z-0 in image class and z-10 on the text div. very visual example here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/appearance

Comment: Remove class `absolute` from the text div

Comment: Thanks, but when i view on mobile view text shows next to icon instead of below.

Comment: Note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove absolute class

```
  <link
  rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
/>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap mt-4 border-2 border-gray-500 p-8 m-auto w-1/4  items-center justify-center">
  <div class="fas fa-book-reader text-6xl text-gray-600"></div>
  <div class=" text-base text-center"> Caring Enviroment</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i view on mobile view text shows next to icon instead of below.

Answer (score 1):

Remove absolute or **relpace** absulte with relative. On this way you can position (top-10 etc.) the box if you want.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/TU6xLsUjj4